# Multiple ARIMA simulate through forecast package

Tags: r

I have made a 10 day point forecast for my ARIMA(1,1,1) model and I also found that one is able to simulate future paths with the forecast package.

I therefore use the following code to simulate a 10 day future path.

```
yseries <- Arima(y,order=c(1,1,1))
simyseries <- simulate(yseries,nsim=10)
```

Is there a way to simulate, say, 10 000 future paths with the `simulate()` function?

My final goal is to plot my point forecast together with the simulated paths.

If it isn't possible with the forecast package, is there some other package that lets me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `replicate()`, and then, `matplot()` for multiple plot.

```
y <- ts(arima.sim(model=list(order = c(1,1,1), ar=.8,ma=.7), 100)) # Simulate data
yseries <- Arima(y,order=c(1,1,1))
simyseries <- ts(replicate(10, simulate(yseries, nsim=10)),start=end(y)+1) # Change the first parameter of replicate() to change the number os simulated paths
matplot(cbind(y,simyseries), type='l')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `replicate()` function is useful for repeating a command *n* times (you require that *n* = 10000). It stores the output conveniently.

```
yseriesSims<-replicate(10000,simulate(yseries,nsim=10))
```

The result is a 10 X 10000 matrix of simulations in this case (i.e. the columns contain the individual simulations).